# How can I deliver an Excel VBA app without Rubberduck TestModules?

Tags: excel, vba, unit-testing, rubberduck

I have been using the Rubberduck VBA Add-in.

I want to "deliver" my Excel application without the Rubberduck Add-in in the References. How do you manage that? Is it possible to "hide" the TestModules and not compile them, for instance?

Comment: Seems to me all you need to do is remove the test module(s). I don't think there is a reference to RD in the Tools>References.

Comment: @SmileyFtW that would work, but isn't necessary (plus it then becomes a PITA to export/re-import them for maintenance & deployment)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - Agree it would be a PITA, but if the distributed code gets updated, wouldn't it be from the one in the developer's system and not the user's and an updated one would not depend on one that has been distributed to a user? Of course, a user would then not be able to see the marvelous things RD does.... <g>

Comment: @SmileyFtW in theory, yes.. in practice.... VBA maintenance and deployment isn't exactly standardized :)

Comment: Excellent question. Starred for future reference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your test modules were early-bound (which is a great idea when developing!), then you should remove the reference to the Rubberduck type library before delivering.

Of course you could simply remove the test modules, but that becomes an annoyance of re-importing and exporting... and you don't want to do that.

You *can* ship the project as-is (*with* the test modules, but *without* the reference to Rubberduck), because the test modules won't be in any execution path for the actual live code: **the project won't *compile*, but it will still run fine** (unless someone tries to invoke a test method.. then the test module(s) will be loaded, and the missing library will be noticed by the compiler).

But my recommendation would be to go one step further and late-bind the `AssertClass` instance (and the `FakesProvider`, if you're using that API):

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

'@TestModule
'@Folder("Tests")

Private Assert As Object
Private Fakes As Object

'@ModuleInitialize
Private Sub ModuleInitialize()
    'this method runs once per module.
    Set Assert = CreateObject("Rubberduck.AssertClass")
    Set Fakes = CreateObject("Rubberduck.FakesProvider")
End Sub

'@ModuleCleanup
Private Sub ModuleCleanup()
    'this method runs once per module.
    Set Assert = Nothing
    Set Fakes = Nothing
End Sub
```

With the tests late-bound, the project will now compile with the test modules included. Of course invoking a test method will blow up (unless Rubberduck is on that machine!), but then again the test modules shouldn't be in any execution path of your VBA project.

You can configure Rubberduck to late-bind new test modules by default:

[image: Unit Test Settings]

If you're using "Permissive assert" (it implements type equality in a VBA-like permissive way), the ProgID you'll want to use for late-binding is `Rubberduck.PermissiveAssertClass`.

A relatively new possible configuration, is "dual binding", which sets up new test modules as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

'@TestModule
'@Folder("Tests")

#Const LateBind = LateBindTests

#If LateBind Then
    Private Assert As Object
    Private Fakes As Object
#Else
    Private Assert As Rubberduck.PermissiveAssertClass
    Private Fakes As Rubberduck.FakesProvider
#End If

'@ModuleInitialize
Private Sub ModuleInitialize()
    'this method runs once per module.
    #If LateBind Then
        Set Assert = CreateObject("Rubberduck.PermissiveAssertClass")
        Set Fakes = CreateObject("Rubberduck.FakesProvider")
    #Else
        Set Assert = New Rubberduck.PermissiveAssertClass
        Set Fakes = New Rubberduck.FakesProvider
    #End If
End Sub

'@ModuleCleanup
Private Sub ModuleCleanup()
    'this method runs once per module.
    Set Assert = Nothing
    Set Fakes = Nothing
End Sub
```

Configured like this, you can easily toggle between late and early binding modes:

```
#Const LateBind = True '/False
```

If you have multiple test modules, you can define a project-level precompiler constant named `LateBindTests`, and toggle late/early binding for all Rubberduck test modules at once. You can do this in the *Project Properties* (from the Tools menu, or right-click your project in the *Code Explorer* and select *Project Properties*):

[image: Project Properties VBIDE dialog]

<sub>(side note: the *Help File* project property (no one uses that, right?) is being hijacked by Rubberduck to assign and persist a unique ID to the project - changing this value without immediately saving & closing *will* break stuff)</sub>

Comment: FWIW, if you want to have a global switch because you have multiple test modules, you can define the flag in the project's properties (via the Debug menu).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Great answer ! I knew there was something around late binding ... My mistake was to chip it with early binding and without removing the rubberduck references ... Thank you !